# repeating dd/mm/yyyy regex with separator

Tags: regex, validation, date, repeat, regex-greedy

I'm working on client validation and in some cases my users are allowed to choose a date range or several dates at the same times with a date picker.

I found this regex to valid simple date :

```
Date regex 

^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

This one allows many format :

dd/mm/yyyy

dd-mm-yyyy

dd.mm.yyyy

In the first case (date range), I use ' - ' as separator and I want to check the selected range with a regex :

```
01/02/2018 - 02/03/2018
```

I worked around and I am able to do this with a simplier regex :

```
^((\d{2})(?:\ \-\ |)){2}$

on this string

02 - 03
```

When I replace the first part (\d{2}) with my date regex and test the showed date range (01/02/2018 - 02/03/2018), the regex doesn't match.

In the second case(several dates selected), I'm using ',' as separator and I'm looking for a greedy quantifier solution.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to cover so many different formats to begin with? If you are using a datepicker component, isn’t the date return format already _specified_ by that …?

Comment: Yes It does, but I'm also thinking about globalization or custom date format depending on user's preferences. Even if my date regex is wrapped by parentheses, do you think the regex complexity could be a problem in my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your regex to select range with seperator comma or minus

```
([0-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(\/|-|\.)([0][0-9]|[1][0-2])(\/|-|\.)(\d{4})\s(-|,)\s([0-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(\/|-|\.)([0][0-9]|[1][0-2])(\/|-|\.)(\d{4})
```

It works in so many cases as follows

INPUT

```
# dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy   01/02/2018 - 02/03/2018   01/02/2018 , 02/03/2018

# dd-mm-yyyy - dd-mm-yyyy   01-02-2018 - 02-03-2018   01-02-2018 , 02-03-2018

# dd.mm.yyyy - dd.mm.yyyy   01.02.2018 - 02.03.2018   01.02.2018 , 02.03.2018
```

OUTPUT

```
# 01/02/2018 - 02/03/2018   01/02/2018 , 02/03/2018

# 01-02-2018 - 02-03-2018   01-02-2018 , 02-03-2018

# 01.02.2018 - 02.03.2018   01.02.2018 , 02.03.2018
```

Comment: That's perfect !